# Empty string increasing size by one in C++

Tags: c++

The following code snippets output different results for the same input (7747774):

A:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string N;
    cin >> N;

    int K = count(N.begin(), N.end(), '4') + count(N.begin(), N.end(), '7');
    string C = to_string(K);
    bool lucky = (K>0) && (count(C.begin(), C.end(), '4') + count(C.begin(), C.end(), '7') == C.size());
    cout << (lucky?"YES":"NO") << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

B:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string N;
    cin >> N;

    int K = count(N.begin(), N.end(), '4') + count(N.begin(), N.end(), '7');
    string C = "" + K;
    bool lucky = (K>0) && (count(C.begin(), C.end(), '4') + count(C.begin(), C.end(), '7') == C.size());
    cout << (lucky?"YES":"NO") << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

A prints YES, while B prints NO, as size of 'C' in B has increased by one. Why is that?

Comment: `"" + K` is not right, this is not Java

Comment: Not the problem here, but you can avoid some stress and extra work by reserving SHOUTCASE names for macros, and by generally not using single letter names. The two main exceptions are loop counter variables, conventionally `i`, `j` and `k`, and a template type argument, conventionally `T`. However, for the latter I prefer to break convention and write `Type`.

Comment: @yassin: It's bad style in Java as well. One ought to use `String.valueOf(K)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string C = "" + K;
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You probably think it is equivalent to `std::to_string(K)`, well no. What it *actually* does is increment the pointer of the string literal `""` by `K`.

That's undefined behavior (as `K` is not `0` - that wouldn't change the pointer), and you can get any result. You have to use `std::to_string` or `std::atoi` or similar functions.

Comment: Technically `""+K` is defined behaviour if `K` is zero or one.  (In the latter case, the pointer points after the null byte at the end of the string.)  Of course dereferencing that after-the-end pointer to convert it to string is UB.

Answer (score 1):

`"" + K` is an operation between a `const char*` and an `int`. It's equivalent conceptually to `&(""[K])`

You create a `std::string` from a pointer you obtained mistakenly. It points to an unspecified location, and using it to construct your `std::string` is relying on undefined behavior.

A funny thing is that if you were to use a `std::string` literal, you'd get a compiler error:

```
string C = ""s + K;
```